# LSTM - run model.fit(epochs=1) 100 times performs better than running 1 time with epochs=100

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

It just turns out my bellow training behaves big difference on the training performance

method 1, I run bellow code 10 times

```
model.fit(x_train_lstm, y_train_lstm, epochs=2, shuffle=False, batch_size=32)
```

method 2, run bellow code 1 times(I can also change the epochs to 1000)

```
model.fit(x_train_lstm, y_train_lstm, epochs=100, shuffle=False, batch_size=32)
```

the difference is method 1 gains much better result,

So in short, it is impossible for me to use method 2 to reach more than 0.6 accuracy, it is possible to use method 1 but too difficult:

```
76/76 [==============================] - 8s 100ms/step - loss: 0.6638 - accuracy: 0.5950
```

while method 2 gets worse and worse retults, bellow is print after more 100 times training:

```
76/76 [==============================] - 8s 108ms/step - loss: 0.6956 - accuracy: 0.5298
```

How can that happen? What shoudl I do?

here is my model:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 lstm (LSTM)                 (None, 100, 60)           16800     
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 100, 60)           0         
                                                                 
 lstm_1 (LSTM)               (None, 100, 60)           29040     
                                                                 
 dropout_1 (Dropout)         (None, 100, 60)           0         
                                                                 
 lstm_2 (LSTM)               (None, 30)                10920     
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 1)                 31        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 56,791
Trainable params: 56,791
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I have done more than 5 rounds test, my test includes bellow cases:

1. call `sns.set()` and `tf.compat.v1.random.set_random_seed(1234)` before I execute the above comparation tests, and rebuild the model, it shows the first method runs better
2. without rebuild the model, without reset random seed, just run method 1 and method 2, after method 1 improves the accuracy run method 2 will just reduce the acuracy, and later I run method 1 manually again, it improces accuracy again

Comment: This is not a huge difference, the loss is only barely different, and you are forgetting about random weight initialization, so this comparison makes no sense (your results could be explained by different starting random weights).

Comment: I forget mention, I have done seed before everytime I do the seed with, sns.set()
tf.compat.v1.random.set_random_seed(1234)

and I tested more than 5 rounds confirmed the case